# Function verbosity when returning boolean value?

Tags: php

Consider:

```
function something($x, $y)
{
   if($x == $y){
      return True; 
   }
}
```

If the the condition in the segment does not evaluate to true, does php require me to 
explicitly return false?

Example:

```
$condition = something(1,3);
if(!$something){///}
```

Will `$condition` evaluate to false if declared like above?

Comment: Given that `$x` and `$y` don't exist in `something()`, you're comparing null with null; and `null == null` equates to true

Comment: Ignoring that `return ($x == $y);`

Comment: Sorry, edited for clarification, assuming values are set.

Comment: Well you still need to pass the two values when you call `something()`

Comment: And you probably want `if(!$condition)`

Comment: OK.... now a null will be returned, which equates to a falsey condition

Comment: So the purpose is to determine when I need to explicitly return true or false.

Comment: Easier to explicitly return true/false with `function something($x, $y)
{
   return $x == $y;
}`

Comment: Don't simply work on assumptions.... make it obvious to anybody else reading the code.... with PHP7, you'll even have the option of return type hinting to make it very obvious

Comment: So if condition is not met and `return false` isn't declared, a null will evaluate as false?

Comment: Yes, a `null` will evaluate as `false` in a loose comparison - http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php - this is well documented